# Place a Ribbon on a Root Site

Tags: ribbon

I have created a Ribbon following an example. However, the only examples I can find place the Ribbon on a document list. I suspect that a change is needed here:

```
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
RegistrationId="101"
RegistrationType="List"
```

Which values should I use here to get the Ribbon to appear on the root site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure where you want the ribbon but I am guessing that you have not created a Ribbon itself but trying to customize an existing ribbon.

SharePoint has displays Ribbon (which can be customized) at several fixed locations and those locations are documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537543.aspx

You can customize instances of ribbons documented above and ribbon customizations includes creating a new tab, a new group under a tab or adding a new button. Chris has a nice series of blog entries for ribbon. You can start here: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you cannot do this via registration, but you could try to [Customize the ribbon programmatically from web parts and field controls](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/02/customize-ribbon-programmatically-from.html) as suggested by [Chris O'Brien](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com).

Answer (score 1):

Although I have no direct answer for you, the way I usually approach this is as follows:

- Click on a button on the ribbon bar you want to add this button to / any button for which you want to copy the behaviour
- Write down the aspx file this button links to
- Search in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES for all files containing that file name.
- Hopefully this will return the definition for the ribbon button you want to copy.